# I get invalid return on a Kitty problem in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

**Hi everyone. The problem is too long for me to paste it here so I will paste a URL instead. I get 50% invalid returns. I added a check if a cat has hit a deadlock to collect food/soul on that cell. I have been tackling this issue since 6 am and it is 11am now and I am getting to the point of frustration.**

Briefly the problem is the following:
Your task is to calculate the food and the souls collected by Kitty or to output that she is deadlocked.

On the first line of the input you will receive the positions of the coder souls ("@"), food ("*") and deadlocks ("x") as string.

On the second line of the input you will receive the path of the Kitty as string with integers separated by single space. Positive means, move to the right, negative means, move to the left.

The starting position will always be at index 0.

The final result is either the souls, food and deadlocks count or a string informing that the Kitty is deadlocked. The format is shown in the zero tests and the example.

@ - symbol for coder soul
* - symbol for food
x - symbol for deadlock

**More details below:
https://judge.telerikacademy.com/problem/30kitty**

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int deadlocks = 0;        
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] output = input2.Split(' ');
        int position = 0;
        int startposition = 0;

        int codersoulscollected = 0;
        int foodcollected = 0;

        int iterations = Math.Max(input.Length, output.Length);
        bool[] isCollected = new bool[input.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++)
        {

            startposition += position;
            if (startposition < 0)
            {
                startposition = input.Length + startposition;
            }
            if (startposition >= input.Length)
            {
                startposition = startposition - input.Length;
            }
            char a = input[startposition];
            if (a == '@' && (isCollected[startposition] == false))
            {
                codersoulscollected++;
                isCollected[startposition] = true;
            }
            if (a == '*' && (isCollected[startposition] == false))
            {
                foodcollected++;
                isCollected[startposition] = true;
            }
            if (a == 'x' && (isCollected[startposition] == false))
            {
                deadlocks++;

                if (startposition % 2 == 0)
                {
                    codersoulscollected--;
                    isCollected[startposition] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    foodcollected--;
                    isCollected[startposition] = true;
                }
            }
            else if (a == 'x' && (isCollected[startposition] == true))
            {

                if (startposition % 2 == 0)
                {
                    codersoulscollected++;

                }
                else
                {
                    foodcollected++;

                }
            }
            if (output.Length == i)
            {
                break;
            }
            position = int.Parse(output[i]);

            if (foodcollected < 0 || codersoulscollected < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are deadlocked, you greedy kitty!");
                Console.WriteLine($"Jumps before deadlock: {i}");
                return;
            }

        }


        if (foodcollected >= 0 || codersoulscollected >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Coder souls collected: {codersoulscollected}\r\nFood collected: {foodcollected}\r\nDeadlocks: {deadlocks}");
        }
```

Comment: Does it give details of your failures? ie what inputs caused it to fail and why? Also looking at `int iterations = Math.Max(input.Length, output.Length);` - this doesn't seem to match the spec as far as I can see...

Comment: Since this is a coding test for your skills I will only give you a hint. You are using c# an object oriented language, yet you are not using any of it. First start by defining a Cat class, then define a class for Path. Maybe your Cat class should also have some methods like Go left or Go right

Comment: @Chris unfortunately it only says IR.

Comment: @hasan this is part of the functional programming. Not part of the OOP.

Comment: @grozdeto, then it is even worse. There is not a single code that is looking like functional programming, everything is imperative

Comment: @Chris can you elaborate on that?

Comment: ACtually, I missed a line later in your code. I thought you were going to iterate more than you did but for some reason you chose to iterate based on input length but then break early if you get to the end of output. Why not just base your for loop on output?

Comment: @Chris you are right. I have corrected it to be the output. However, I still have IR on 50% of the cases.

Comment: Without having a way to actually reproduce your problem its kind of hard to work out what is going wrong. My only suggestion is to create a bunch of test cases of all different sorts. You should be able to verify manually what the results should be and confirm its the same as your program outputs. Think of things that will test each part of your program (eg one that checks you are doing the path correctly, one that is making sure you are incrementing food correctly, etc.).

Comment: I'm afraid for the time being I have had to vote to close. To quote the close reason "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." If you can include a specific fail case that you don't understand though then update the question and it will be good again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had some time at my hand, I wrote a simple solution for you which walks you step by step in an OOP manner. Hopefully you can see your problem as well.

This is your cat. It can walk the given amount of steps on a given Path. It also collects food and soul etc.

```
public class Cat
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Amount of collected coder souls.
    /// </summary>
    private int _coderSouls;

    /// <summary>
    /// Amount of collected food.
    /// </summary>
    private int _food;

    /// <summary>
    /// Amount of deadlocks collected.
    /// </summary>
    private int _deadlocks;

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of jumps before deadlocking.
    /// Starts from -1 because When we set the path
    /// The kitty starts from the 0th tile.
    /// </summary>
    private int _numberOfJumps = -1;

    /// <summary>
    /// If Cat can still move.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _deadLocked;

    /// <summary>
    /// Path to follow.
    /// </summary>
    private Path _path;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Kitty
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Path for Kitty</param>
    public Cat(Path path)
    {
        SetPath(path);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the path for Kitty to follow.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Path to follow.</param>
    private void SetPath(Path path)
    {
        _path = path;
        Walk(0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Walks the Kitty with the given amount of steps.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="step">Amount of steps</param>
    /// <returns>If kitty can move any more.</returns>
    public bool Walk(int step)
    {
        // If Kitty is deadlocked it can not move any more
        if (_deadLocked)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Walks the cat with the given step amount
        var got = _path.MoveToNext(step);
        // Increase the number of Jumps
        _numberOfJumps++;
        // Rule written in the question
        switch (got)
        {
            case ItemType.CoderSoul:
                _coderSouls++;
                break;

            case ItemType.Food:
                _food++;
                break;

            case ItemType.DeadLock:
                _deadlocks++;
                var isEven = _path.GetPosition() % 2 == 0;
                if (isEven)
                {
                    if (_coderSouls > 0)
                    {
                        _coderSouls--;
                        return true;
                    }
                    _deadLocked = true;
                    return false;
                }
                if (_food > 0)
                {
                    _food--;
                    return true;
                }
                _deadLocked = true;
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When Kitty finished moving, Gets Summary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Summary of movemebt</returns>
    public string Summarize()
    {
        return _deadLocked ? PrepareDeadLockMessage() : PrepareSummaryMessage();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deadlock message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Deadlock message.</returns>
    private string PrepareDeadLockMessage()
    {
        return $"You are deadlocked, you greedy kitty!{Environment.NewLine}Jumps before deadlock: {_numberOfJumps}";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Normal finish.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Normal finish.</returns>
    private string PrepareSummaryMessage()
    {
        return $"Coder souls collected: {_coderSouls}{Environment.NewLine}Food collected: {_food}{Environment.NewLine}Deadlocks: {_deadlocks}";
    }


}
```

This is your path. You have to parse it as it was given in the question.

```
public class Path
{
    private readonly Item[] path;
    private int _currentIndex;

    public Path(string pathElements)
    {
        path = pathElements.Select(t => new Item(t)).ToArray();
        _currentIndex = 0;
    }

    public ItemType MoveToNext(int increase)
    {
        _currentIndex += increase;
        if (_currentIndex > path.Length)
        {
            _currentIndex -= path.Length;
        }
        if (_currentIndex < 0)
        {
            _currentIndex += path.Length;
        }
        return path[_currentIndex].Collect();
    }

    public int GetPosition()
    {
        return _currentIndex;
    }
}
```

This is your single item in your given cell.

```
public class Item
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Kitty already collected this cell or not?
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsCollected { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ItemType in this cell
    /// </summary>
    public ItemType ItemType { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a single item in each cell.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="c">Type of the item decided by char.</param>
    public Item(char c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '@':
                ItemType = ItemType.CoderSoul;
                break;

            case '*':
                ItemType = ItemType.Food;
                break;

            case 'x':
                ItemType = ItemType.DeadLock;
                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Collect the item in this cell.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The collected item.</returns>
    public ItemType Collect()
    {
        if (IsCollected)
        {
            return ItemType.None;
        }
        IsCollected = true;
        return ItemType;
    }
}
```

And finally this is your ItemTypes that can be contained in each cell

```
/// <summary>
/// The type of item located in each single cell.
/// </summary>
public enum ItemType
{
    None,
    CoderSoul,
    Food,
    DeadLock,
}
```

This is how you use this example. Please go through each step with a debugger.

```
var cat = new Cat(new Path("x@*@*@*"));
var walkinOrder = "1 -1 -1 4";
var intOrder = walkinOrder.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse);
foreach (var step in intOrder) {
    if (cat.Walk(step) == false)
    {
    break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(cat.Summarize());
```

Comment: The happiness I get after 8 months that I helped someone :)